# How to check if date exceeds more than seven days

Tags: java, date, compare

I would like to check if two date exceeds a week, like, check if two dates have seven days,

at point the data range should be within a week only(7 Days).

i have tried something like this,

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class IsDateRangeExceedsWeek 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) 
    {
        try{

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date fromDate = sdf.parse("2015-05-01");
            Date toDate = sdf.parse("2015-05-07");

            System.out.println(sdf.format(fromDate));
            System.out.println(sdf.format(toDate));

            if(fromDate.compareTo(toDate)>0){
                System.out.println("From Date should be less than To Date");
            } else if(fromDate.compareTo(toDate)==0){
                System.out.println("From Date is equal to To Date");
            } 

        }catch(ParseException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Could some one help ?

Comment: U can use calendar class.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [Jodatime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) and use

```
Days.daysBetween(start, end).getDays()
```

Another solution is to use Calendar, add 7 days and compare again.

```
  Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
  c.setTime(fromDate);
  c.add(Calendar.DATE,7);
  if(c.getTime().compareTo(toDate)<0){
    It's more than 7 days.
  }
```

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See the [correct Answer by Misha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30207933/642706) for how to use *java.time*.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Yeah I know about that. But my answer is more than 3 years old. Java 8 was just released then and I don't think anyone (including me) wasn't using it yet ;) If I was asked now I would vote for the other answer using java.time

Comment: My comments are not criticisms of your original writing (correct and useful when written), just “FYI” facts for today’s readers.

Comment: Yeah - its completely valid. I even upvoted the other answer ;)

Answer (score 20):

Using the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later:

```
LocalDate from = LocalDate.parse("2015-05-01");
LocalDate to = LocalDate.parse("2015-05-07");

long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(from, to);    // 6 days
long weeks = ChronoUnit.WEEKS.between(from, to);  // 0 weeks
```

Comment: ✔ This is the correct and most modern Answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can try like this:

```
if(Days.daysBetween(fromDate,toDate ).getDays()>7)
```

Check [JodaTime API](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/index.html)

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). See the [correct Answer by Misha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30207933/642706) for how to use *java.time*.