# Check if date is one week before from today Java

Tags: java, android, date

I am trying to check if a particular date is one week before from today's date. I formatted my date into this format:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");
```

Then, I get the list of date from a for loop by these code:

```
Date formattedToday = formatter.parse(todayStr);
Date formattedExpired = formatter.parse(expiredDate);
```

The example of dates in the list are:

```
09/12/2017 08:09 PM
10/24/2015 02:09 AM
07/18/2018 03:10 AM
```

I tried to follow [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207693/how-to-check-if-date-exceeds-more-than-seven-days) but I am not allowed to add in any external libraries.

The other solution that requires `Java 8` is not applicable for me also as my current min **API is 25** but [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) requires `API 26`.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: `if (formattedToday.compareTo(formattedExpired) > 0)` ?

Comment: Why do you have hour components if you're comparing days? Why do you have lists of dates if you're checking a specific date? You should probably show the exact input you have, the exact output you expect, why, and a complete example of code we can run ourselves by copy/pasting it.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: The [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30207933/5772882) in the thread you tried (and the one with most votes) doesn’t require any external libraries if you’re programming for a new Android version (API level 26 or above).

Comment: API level 25, you’re *sooo* close. In that case I would apply for an exception, a permission to use [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP/blob/master/build.gradle) just until you move to API level 26. Once you do that you will just need to change your imports to the built-in java.time and discard ThreeTenABP again. I would consider this the future-proof, convenient and maintenance-friendly solution in every respect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using only `Date` and `Calendar` classes (and thus, compatible with any JVM from about 4-ish, I think?) you could try this sort of solution:

1. Get today as a `Date`: `Date now = new Date()`
2. Get one week ago from that, as a `Calendar`: `Calendar expected = Calendar.getInstance(); expected.setTime(now); lastWeek.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);`
3. Get your expired date as a `Calendar`: `Calendar actual = Calendar.getInstance().setTime(expiredDate);`
4. Compare the year and day of year of the two calendars (you can compare other fields, but those two should be enough): `return (expected.get(Calendar.YEAR) == actual.get(Calendar.YEAR)) && (expected.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) == actual.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));`

Using this, you should be able to come up with an even shorter snippet that subtracts a week from now and compares the long values of the two. Though obviously that wouldn't be comparing calendar dates, it would be comparing nanoseconds :)

Comment: I see I see. I thought of the same way too. But what I did was to get the today's date then minus 7 from it. Then, I used this to check if it is within the date from today to last week: testDate.after(startDate) && testDate.before(endDate)

Comment: Yes that will work too. It uses an extra `Date` object, which may involve extra date calculations, which aren't very cheap. But it might produce more readable code? Your call!

Comment: Note: be careful with subtracting dates. Use `Calendar` for that, always (until you can use JodaTime / Java8). Anything else, and you have to deal with 1 January, 29 February, daylight savings, and many other gotcha-cases. You can't even subtract (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) milliseconds.. that misses daylight savings!

Comment: I am getting incompatible types at step 2! The error message is Required: java.util.Calendar, Found: void

Comment: @hyperfkcb I've provided you with a complete solution which will give you the result you wanted through a one liner from anywhere in your application. :)

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime
.now()                           // Captures current moment as seen by the wall-clock time of the JVM’s current default time zone. Better to pass the optional `ZoneId` argument to specify explicitly the desired/expected time zone.
.minusWeeks( 1 )
.isAfter(
    LocalDateTime
    .parse( 
        "09/12/2017 08:09 PM" ,
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu hh:mm a" , Locale.US )
    )
    .atZone(
        ZoneId.systemDefault()   // Better to pass explicitly the time zone known to have been intended for this input. See discussion below.
    )
)
```

## Using *java.time*

The modern solution uses the *java.time* classes. Much easier to work with that the terrible old legacy `Date`, `Calendar`, etc.

> Check if date is one week before from today Java

Did you intend to work with just the dates, and ignore the time-of-day? I will assume not, as your inputs have a time-of-day.

Get current moment in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Current moment in UTC.
```

Adjust into the time zone implied as the context for you date-time input strings. Apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;      // Replace with the zone you know to have been intended for the input strings.
ZonedDateTime zdtNow = instant.atZone( z ) ;  // Adjust from UTC to a time zone.
```

Subtract a week, a requirement you stated in the Question.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtWeekAgo = zdtNow.minusWeeks( 1 ) ; // Accounts for anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST).
```

Parse your input strings as `LocalDateTime` objects because they lack any indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC.

Tips: If at all possible, change those inputs to include their time zone. And change their formats to use the standard ISO 8601 formats rather than custom format.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu hh:mm a" , Locale.US ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "09/12/2017 08:09 PM" , f ) ;
```

Assign the time zone you know to have been intended for those input strings.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

Compare.

```
boolean moreThanWeekOld = zdt.isBefore( zdtWeekAgo ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Quality post! Why can't I "star" it for future reference? Anyways, I have a question: Joda-Time's website mentions `Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.`; am I supposed to understand that `java.time` is superior to `Joda-Time`? (I have not spent time to learn Joda-Time, hence my question: should I concentrate on java-time instead?)

Comment: @payne The *Joda-Time* project was authored and led by Stephen Colebourne. He then took the lessons learned there to start from scratch in founding JSR 310 and writing its *java.time* implementation. He also led the *ThreeTen-Backport* project to bring most of that functionality to Java 6 & 7 and Android. He also founded and leads the *ThreeTen-Extra* project, that adds more functionality to *java.time*. So, yes, *java.time* is superior to *Joda-Time*, as its official successor. Joda-Time continues to be actively updated for bugs and the *tzdata* file, but will have no more feature work done.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is a complete solution:**

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * @author Jeremi Grenier-Berthiaume
 */
public class InternalDate {

    private int year = 0;
    private int month = 0;
    private int day = 0;


    private InternalDate(int year, int month, int day){
        this.year = year;
        this.month = month;
        this.day = day;
    }

    private static InternalDate generateFromCalendar(Calendar calendar) {

        int lYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int lMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1; // January = 1st month
        int lDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return new InternalDate(lYear, lMonth, lDay);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor for a textual format.
     *
     * @param text  Format "DD/MM/YYYY" followed by more chars which will be ignored if they are present.
     * @return      Associated InternalDate
     */
    private static InternalDate generateDateFromText(String text) {

        int year, month, day;
        char selectedChar = '/';
        text = text.substring(0,10); // to remove hours

        // Extract the data required to construct the InternalDate
        String[] splitDateText = text.split(""+selectedChar);
        day = Integer.parseInt(splitDateText[0]);
        month = Integer.parseInt(splitDateText[1]);
        year = Integer.parseInt(splitDateText[2]);

        return new InternalDate(year, month, day);
    }

    private static InternalDate getLastWeek() {

        // Get current date
        Calendar tempCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        tempCal.setTime(new Date());

        // 7 days ago
        tempCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -7);

        return generateFromCalendar(tempCal);
    }

    public static boolean isLastWeek(String compared) {

        int tmpDate = Integer.parseInt(InternalDate.getLastWeek().getComparableStringDate());
        int tmpCompDate = Integer.parseInt(InternalDate.generateDateFromText(compared).getComparableStringDate());

        return tmpDate == tmpCompDate;
    }
}
```

Forming the date that you want to verify as a string of the format `DD/MM/YYYY` and giving it in input to `InternalDate.isLastWeek(stringDate);` will give you an answer (it returns a boolean: `true` if it's a date from a week ago, `false` if not).

A nice and simple one-liner that you can call from anywhere in your app. Feel free to mark as an answer if it did respond to your question properly. :)

Comment: @hyperfkcb Just curious: which solution did you end up going for?

Comment: I adopted @PaulHicks one as he posted first!

Answer (score 1):

**Java 8 independent**

How about doing it in simple way i.e. get time from two dates and find the `difference`. Convert this `difference` into `days` to get difference between two dates in `days`. Below is working code :

```
Date formattedToday = new Date();
Date formattedExpired = new Date("06/12/2018 08:09 PM");

int diffInDays = (int)( (formattedToday.getTime() - formattedExpired.getTime())
        / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) );

if (diffInDays > 7) 
Log.i("Expiration Status : ", "Expired");
```

It will give you difference between two dates in `days` and it can be `negative` if expiry date is of future and `positive` if expiry date is of past.

Comment: Thanks so much! This works too and it is much more simplified!

Comment: @hyperfkcb Glad to help you!

Comment: Very elegant. It doesn't account for daylight savings though. Not often important.

Comment: There really is no need to use these terrible old classes. The *java.time* classes are built into Java 8 and later. Much of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: @BasilBourque sorry I don't get you exactly but OP don't want to use Java 8 if I understand the question correctly. Is this answer not correct if yes could please help me to understand in more simplified language. thanks!

Comment: Reread the last half of my comment, about *ThreeTen-Backport* & *ThreeTenABP*. Friends don’t let friends use `Date`/`Calendar`/`SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: OP isn't allowed use 3rd-party libraries or Java8+.  We know Calendar/Date are bad, but sometimes (often) your constraints prevent access to the good stuff...

Answer (score 0):

```
Duration.between(new Date().toInstant(), Instant.now()).toDays() < 7)
```

Comment: This code ignores time zones, and assumes 24-hour days. Time zones rules are defined by the whims of politicians. Changes to those rules mean a day may be longer or shorter than 24 hours. A day can be 23 hours long, or 25, or 23.5, or other numbers.